# How can I show all visible tooltips when using jQuery UI with tabs and accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, qtip2

I'm working on a web-application and I use jQuery UI with tabs and accordions and qTip2 (with tooltips).

I'm trying to create a "help" function that would toggle the display of all visible tooltips - and when the user change tab or accordion, then the tooltips should update based on which tooltips that should be visible.

I've created a simple js-fiddle example that illustrates the problem pretty well.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z3My2/8/

HTML:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="mapContainer">
        <div id="simple_map" style="display: inline-block">
            <p title='MapTitle' data-qtip2Enabled>Place map here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="ShowHelp">Show all help messages</button>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#queryTab">Search</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#parametersTab">Search results</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="queryTab">
            <div id='search'>
                <p>Options</p>
                <div id='queryOptions'>
                        <h3>
                        <span id='option1' title='This is option 1' data-qtip2Enabled>Option 1</span>
                    </h3>

                    <div id='option1Div'> <a title="another title" data-qtip2Enabled>Some text</a>

                    </div>
                        <h3>
                        <span id='option2' title='This is option 2' data-qtip2Enabled>Option 2</span>
                    </h3>

                    <div id='option2Div' title="Some Title" style="display: inline-block" data-qtip2Enabled>LaLaLaLALA</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="parametersTab">
            <div id="parametersTabText">Text.
                <br>
                <p title='lorum ipsum' data-qtip2Enabled>More text with tooltip.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- this div is a pop, and don't actually appear -->
    <div id="errorMessageDialog" title="Warning" hidden>this is not a qtip-title (with tag data-qtip2Enabled)</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $('#ShowHelp').click(toggleHelp);
    $("#queryOptions").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
    $('[data-qtip2Enabled]').qtip();
});
var helpEnabled = false;

function enableHelp() {
    unbindHelp();
    $("DIV#tabs li").on("click", function () {
        showHelp();
    });
    $("DIV#search span").on("click", function () {
        showHelp();
    });
    helpEnabled = true;
}

function unbindHelp() {
    $("DIV#tabs li").unbind("click");
    $("DIV#search span").unbind("click");
}

function toggleHelp() {
    if (!helpEnabled) showHelp();
    else {
        helpEnabled = false;
        unbindHelp();
        //$('[data-qtip2Enabled]').qtip('destroy');
        $(".qtip-content").hide();
        $('[data-qtip2Enabled]').qtip({
            show: 'mouseenter',
            hide: 'mouseleave',
        });
    }
}

function showHelp() {
    if (!helpEnabled) enableHelp();
    $(".qtip-content").hide();
    $('[data-qtip2Enabled]').each(function () {
        $(this).qtip({
            show: true,
            hide: false,
            events: {
                focus: function (event, api) {
                    api.set('position.adjust.y', -5);
                },
                blur: function (event, api) {
                    api.set('position.adjust.y', 0);
                },
            },
        });
    });
}
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit: Updated the code and fiddle based on some experiments and Rakesh Singh's answer.

*I'm still wondering how to not display the tooltips that should be hidden - all tooltips are displayed now, but they are updated to the correct places when the UI changes.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put

> ```
> $("DIV#tabs li").on("click",function(){
>     showHelp();
> });
> ```

in jquery ready function.

i hope this will help.

Comment: Good idea, this helps, but it only solves one part of the problem, the second part is to not display the tooltips that are not visible (they are usually displayed in the upper left corner of the screen). I believe that jQuery UI hides element by setting the style to "display: none" - but this property is not inherited, so I can not look for that in "this". The third part I can think of: there could be a lot of tooltips, and generating them seems to require a lot of resources - could it be greatly reduced by not destroying all on each change? And if so: how?

Comment: you can hide tool tip instead of destroying it. using  $(".qtip-content").hide(); you can hide tooltips. so it will not take too much resources.

Comment: Great, thanks. I edited the code based on your answer, but I'm still having some issues.

Comment: can you update code in jsfiddle so i can check issue?

Comment: I did checked you code. Using $(".qtip-content").hide(); or  $('[data-qtip2Enabled]').qtip('destroy');  in both case have same result. Can you described what was the problem using $(".qtip-content").hide();?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, the problem is not in using hide or desotroy, the problem is to hide tooltips that are not supposed to display. When you run the fiddle, and press "show help" before opening any tabs or such, the two tooltips "lorem ipsum" and "another title" should not be displayed, but they are there in the top left corner. jQuery UI has set the style of the parent of the parent (or something like that) of the element to "display: none" - so it is not displayed, but the tooltip is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56336/discussion-between-rakesh-singh-and-plux).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the rest of my problem, and it was a quite simple solution, so I'm marking Rakesh' answer as the accepted since it helped me a lot solving this

The solution to filter out what tooltips to show or not was to add a simple if-sentence:

```
$('#tabs [data-qtip2Enabled]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        $(this).qtip({
            show : true,
            hide : false,
            events : {
                focus : function(event, api) {
                    api.set('position.adjust.y', -5);
                },
                blur : function(event, api) {
                    api.set('position.adjust.y', 0);
                },
            },
        });
    }
});
```

And bind this (with a hide()) to the on-change of $("DIV#tabs li") and $("DIV#tabs h3")